# wicket issue unable to move items from one listmultiplechoice another

Tags: wicket

I have a Wicket Panel. It has two text fields adjacent to each other and two ListMultipleChoice controls adjacent to each other and two buttons "add and remove" in between two these ListMultipleChoice's.

I was unable to move the items from one list box to another unless I entered some values in text fields, which were prior to the list boxes.

If values were entered in text fields, I was able to move the items.

Please find the code below.

```
TextField<BigDecimal> textfield1 = new TextField<BigDecimal>("value1")
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8199976201679629866L;

    @Override
    public IConverter getConverter(Class<?> type) {
        return new FixedDecimalPlacesConverter();
    }

};
textfield1.setType(BigDecimal.class);
textfield1.setLabel(new Model<String>("Value1"));
textfield1.setRequired(true)
.add(PositiveNumberValidator.getInstance())
.add(new FixedDecimalPlacesValidator(2));
add(new FeedBackBorder("Border1").add(textfield1));

TextField <BigDecimal> textfield2 = new TextField<BigDecimal>("value2")
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8199976201679629866L;

    @Override
    public IConverter getConverter(Class<?> type) {
        return new FixedDecimalPlacesConverter();
    }

};
textfield2.setType(BigDecimal.class);
textfield2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
textfield2.setLabel(new Model<String>("Value2"));
textfield2.setRequired(true)
.add(PositiveNumberValidator.getInstance())
.add(new FixedDecimalPlacesValidator(2));
add (new FeedBackBorder("Border2").add(textfield2));

ChoiceRenderer<UserBean> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<UserBean>("userName", "userID.ID");

availableUsers= new ListMultipleChoice<UserBean>( "availableUsersBean", availableUsersList, choiceRenderer );
availableUsers.setOutputMarkupId(true);
availableUsers.setLabel(new Model<String>("Available Users"));
add(new FeedBackBorder("availableUsersBorder").add(availableUsers));

selectedUsers = new ListMultipleChoice<UserBean>( "selectedUsersBean", selectedUsersList, choiceRenderer );
selectedUsers.setOutputMarkupId(true);
selectedUsers.setLabel(new Model<String>("Selected Users"));
add(new FeedBackBorder("selectedUsers Border").add(selectedUsers ));

add = new AjaxButton("add") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
        update(target, availableUsers.getModelValue(),availableUsers, selectedUsers);
    }
};
add(new FeedBackBorder("addBorder").add(add));

remove = new AjaxButton("remove") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
        update(target, selectedUsers.getModelValue(), selectedUsers , availableUsers);
    }
};
add(new FeedBackBorder("removeBorder").add(remove));
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using the `Palette` component?

Comment: yes, palette UI is different (ex: images for Add, remove buttons)..my UI requires me not to have the Palete component...

Comment: As of Wicket 1.4.13, the Palette component allows the images to be customized via CSS (see the Jira ticket here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1779). You could also override the HTML for the component.

Comment: what is in the update method ?

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance: Your TextFields are required. Submitting the Form via AjaxButtons wouldn't trigger the `onSubmit` method for an invalid form but the `onError` method.

Possible Solutions (in no particular order):

- Moving the Lists to a nested form
- Moving the contents of the `onSubmit` to a separate method and call it from `onError` too
- Move the item moving logic to a pure JavaScript based Behaviour or Decorator that doesn't trigger a form submit.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why did you change all the classnames to lower case?

Answer (score 0):

`add.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
remove.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);`

I am using org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Button which allows you to turn off full form submit with button click with the `setDefaultFormProcessing(boolean)`.  This should allow you to process actions without submitting your complete form, therefore not validating required textfields.